# Connecting to SQL Express DB: connection refused

Tags: java, sql-server, dependencies

I have SQL **Express** 2012 installed on my local machine. I tried connecing with it, by using [JDBC 6.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java). I downloaded it and declared the dependency(IntelliJ: CTRL, SHIFT, ALT + S --> "Modules" --> "Add" --> "Jars or directories").

Eventually I adjusted the provided code above to my needs, looking like the following:

For some reason, the imported class is not being used at all(it´s greyed out by IntelliJ) - did I made a mistake in terms of dependencies? I´m fairly new to JAVA: to my understanding, setting up the classpath is equal to setting up the depndencies(?).

Moreover I get the error "connection refused". I checked different login credentials as well as the ports(SQL configuration manager as well as netstate) - they are fine. Both, Windows- and SQL authentication didn´t work.

What am I missing?

```
package com.company;

import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                +"database=QMT;"
                +"user=superadmin;"
                +"password=myPassword.;";

        // Declare the JDBC objects.
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use telnet localhost 1433?

Comment: Express is installed as a named instance, it doesn't seat on 1433 and to connect to it you should use INSTANCE NAME. Or you can find its CORRECT port in CM or in errorlog and pass it with correct IP address

Comment: So first type the correct instance name, localhost\SQLEXPRESS. Then if you need to connect not only from your local pc, launch SQL Server Browser or pass in the correct port

Comment: @sepupic I tried("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLEXPRESS:1433;"), I get the same error. I called the instance "MSSQLEXPRESS"(on installation) though.

Comment: Please post here the picture of configuration manager that shows the correct instance name.

Comment: @sepupic I meant "MSSQLSERVER" https://i.imgur.com/RKcH0rg.png

Comment: Ok, you made it default instance, so the port is really 1433 I think. Did you try to connect the server using SSMS or sqlcmd?

Comment: "connection refused" is not a server error but your java error. Maybe you've reached the server but have problems with your credentials. Can you check SQL Server error log for errors "login failed for user..."?

Comment: @sepupic Thanks for your help so far. The log doesnt provide any information(it´s empty for the timespan).

Comment: At the beginning of the log it writes the correct port, is it 1433? If there is no "login failed", you didn't reach the server

Comment: @sepupic No, there is no information about that(see the time): https://i.imgur.com/IUKfmEm.png Looks like I dont even reach the server.

Comment: You showed me the last records, not the first. Scroll down to the beginning or use xp_readerrorlog in query window. But if you successfully use SSMS, can you show me your connection string in SSMS?

Comment: By the way there is recent LOGIN FAILED FOR SA BECAUSE OF INCORRECT PASSWORD (STATE 8)

Comment: @sepupic I think my SQl installation is wrong for some reason...after a reboot I cant restart the services. I will reinstall the express edition. Do you know if JDBC 6.2 supports SQL Express 2016?Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Before you uninstall please check errorlog one more time, it will show you the reason. Maybe you have installed 2 instances ant put them both on 1433? What is the startup type for your sql server, is it Automatic or Manual?

Comment: @sepupic It is automatic, I tried also manual though. The errorlog doesn´t seem to provide any information about this incident...

Comment: There is information, maybe it's event viewer that doesn't show it, you can open errorlog even with notepad, so please find the last errorlog and open it manually

Comment: @sepupic problem is, I cant start the server(as mentioned above). Do you knwo where the default windows path to the log you looking for is?

Comment: This depends on a version and instance name, smth like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SMSQLSERVER\LOG, the file of interest is the most recent file, it tells you why the instance failed to start. The previous one will tell you what was the correct instance name and the port

Comment: @sepupic found it: http://imgur.com/AecK5dA

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2023869/sql-server-fails-to-start-with-error-17182-tdssniclient-initialization

Comment: Is it a requirement to use SSL encryption? Your problem is not reguarding your server but your encryption certificate. May be you can just not use it at all?

Comment: @sepupic I have to clarify that. You helped me a lot though - thank you! Last question: do you know whether JDBC 6.2 is compatible with SQL Express 2016?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't use java so I don't know the answer. But your server has no problem, it's a certificate error and if you don't need to use SSL just uncheck using encryption both in Configuration Manager for your server and for your client connection

Comment: Now I think your connection string was right but the connection was refused because the client did not use the encryption, but your server is configurated to use it